# Loading LOB data from CSV to tables using SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a CSV file which contains data in the format `<id>,<blobdata>`, which is produced by a data export form another table.

I am trying to load the data into a table using SQL*Loader, but get error "Field in data file exceeds maximum length". Below is the control file which I am using:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
load data 
infile 'ImportFiles\CustPics.csv' 
truncate
into table CustPics 
fields terminated by ","  optionally enclosed by '"' (CustID,PIC_BLOB)
```

Comment: did you check target table's filed lengths? It seems that they are too short for your data

Comment: @ Plirkeee - In the CSV table i have data exported from a blob field. The same data i am trying to load in a blob field of another table.

Comment: How did you export the BLOB to a text file - the mechanism used, and how you converted the binary data to plain text? Can you show an example line from the CSV file, the maximum text length of that field in your file, and the table definitions? I'm guessing it's more than 4000 bytes. Why are you trying to move BLOB data around like this - why not use export/import?